# Broadcast através de uma rota no Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, express.js, socket.io

Tenho um endpoint em uma aplicação node que quando chamada deve disparar um broadcast para os usuários conectados na aplicação node.
Ou seja, assim que o usuário entrasse no sistema ele se conectaria através do socket.io e ficaria aguardando até que um agente externo chamasse essa rota para ai sim ser disparado a mensagem para quem estivesse conectado. Isso é possível ? Não sei se fui claro o bastante. Estou usando para isso express e socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

Sem dúvida, é possível sim. Veja um exemplo:

No servidor, `app.js`

```
var _   = require('lodash');
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io  = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(80);

var sockets = {};

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/oi', function(req, res) {
  enviaParaTodos(req.body);
});

io.on('connection', guardaConexao);

function guardaConexao(socket) {
  socket.on('error', console.log);
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    delete sockets[socket.id];
  });
  sockets[socket.id] = socket;
}

function enviaParaTodos(dados) {
  _.forOwn(sockets, function (socket, id) {
    socket.emit('oi', dados);
  });
}
```

No cliente, `index.html`

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('oi', alert);
</script>
```